# Handle Exception for “Address already in use: bind” when running Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Do we have any mechanism to catch the "Address already in use" exception in Spring Boot so we can have non-technical message deliver to end-user?

Is Global Exception working for this case?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you just catch the exception and handle it there?

Comment: Oh, it is from Spring Boot internally

Comment: But doesn't the `SpringApplication.run` method throw the exception?

Comment: If am not wrong. this exception occur because SpringBoot is trying to start a embedded Tomcat container on a port which is already in use. So technically your application isn't deployed yet. So you cant catch that exception.

Comment: @JacobG. We got only a message "Exception in Application init method"

Comment: @AshishKumar. that is a question, how my application catch the exception?

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala. your comment is not useful

Comment: If "application" you are referring to is "Spring Application". Then you can't catch that exception...

Comment: @AshishKumar: yes it is Spring Boot application

Comment: non technical message? What? This means you are already running something on that port, you spring boot application has *failed* to start up. You should either run it on a different port, or stop whatever application is running on that port

Comment: @DarrenForsythe: we would like to show a message like 'It seems the application is already running by someone else. Please contact Admin for more information'

Comment: I would really question why, given where the exception is thrown from you would likely need to intercept it as I don't believe there are any hook for this. Maybe some documentation and knowledge sharing is a better alternative than over-engineering for something so simple.

Comment: Our client doesn't have much computer knowledge. We are trying to show them more information when any wrong happens.